# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.6, seaborn

I am on ubuntu 18.04 and was trying to visualize the correlation matrix on the pandas data frame. Here is the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK3Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data=pd.read_csv("/home/mv/PycharmProjects/pratice1/airfoil_self_noise.csv")
print(data.columns)
print(data.isnull().any().any())
print(data.isnull().sum().sum()) 
#plt.matshow(data.corr())
#plt.show()
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
corr = data.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool), 
cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),
        square=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

but on executing the above code, it gives the following error -

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: Can you show some data?

Comment: I am using this database for implementation https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Airfoil+Self-Noise